# Can I use google authentication with an sql database?

Tags: php, sql, sqlite, authentication, google-plus

I'm currently working on my first web app with an actual database, and I'm wondering if I can use the google+ sign in api to authenticate an sql/sqlite database on my server in php.  Does anyone know if I can, and if so, how?